# Login Account Error

Tags: python

I am trying to make a text based account system. Basically a user creates a acccount and the information is saved to a dictionary called **accounts**. There are two parts to every account, the username and password. When saving the information to the **accounts** dictionary it is saved as accounts[newusername] = newpassword. Anyhow the login function I made does not work, anything I type in it does not work, it just says the stuff I am putting in is wrong.

Here is my login code:

```
def login():
    username = ""
    password = ""
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n Would you like to login?"
    yesorno = raw_input("\n Please enter YES or NO: ")
    if yesorno.lower() == "no":
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        startup()
    elif yesorno.lower() == "yes":
        while username == "":
            username = raw_input("\n Please enter your username: ")
        while password == "":
            password = raw_input("\n Please enter your password: ")
        for usernames in accounts:
            if username.lower() == usernames.lower():
                for passwords in accounts.values():
                    if password == passwords:
                        print "\n Access Granted"
                        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                        menu()
                    else:
                        pass
                    print "\n Access Denied"
                    print "\n Please try again"
                    login()
            else:
                pass
            print "\n Access Denied"
            print "\n Please try again"
            login()
    else:
        login()
```

Then here is my full code for the entire thing:

```
import datetime
import time
import pickle

filesfile = "filesfiles"
accountfile = "accountsfiles"

accounts = {}
files = {}

accountsaver = open(accountfile,'r')
accounts = pickle.load(accountsaver)
accountsaver.close()

filesaver = open(filesfile,'r')
files = pickle.load(filesaver)
filesaver.close()

def startup():
    accountsaver = open(accountfile,'wb')
    pickle.dump(accounts, accountsaver)   
    accountsaver.close()
    print "\n          -------------------          "
    print "          FILE SYSTEM MANAGER          "
    print "          -------------------          "
    print "\n To login type in: LOGIN"
    print " To create a new account type in: ACCOUNT"
    loginornew = raw_input("\n Please enter LOGIN or ACCOUNT: ")
    if loginornew.lower() == "login":
        login()
    elif loginornew.lower() == "account":
        newaccount()
    else:
        startup()

def newaccount():
    newusername = ""
    newpassword = ""
    newpasswordagain = ""
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n Would you like to create a new account?"
    yesorno = raw_input("\n Please enter YES or NO: ")
    if yesorno.lower() == "no":
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        startup()
    elif yesorno.lower() == "yes":
        while newusername == "":
            newusername = raw_input("\n Please enter a username for your account: ")
        while newpassword == "":    
            newpassword = raw_input(" Please enter a password for your account: ")
        while newpasswordagain == "":
            newpasswordagain = raw_input(" Please confirm the password for your account: ")
        if newpassword == newpasswordagain:
            for username in accounts:
                if username.lower() == newusername.lower():
                    print "\n Username already exists"
                    print " Please try again"
                    newaccount()
                else:
                    pass
            accounts[newusername] = newpassword
            print "\n Account Created"
            print "\n--------------------------------------------"
            startup()
        else:
            print "\n Passwords do not match"
            print " Please try again"
            newaccount()
    else:
        newaccount()

def login():
    username = ""
    password = ""
    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
    print "\n Would you like to login?"
    yesorno = raw_input("\n Please enter YES or NO: ")
    if yesorno.lower() == "no":
        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
        startup()
    elif yesorno.lower() == "yes":
        while username == "":
            username = raw_input("\n Please enter your username: ")
        while password == "":
            password = raw_input("\n Please enter your password: ")
        for usernames in accounts:
            if username.lower() == usernames.lower():
                for passwords in accounts.values():
                    if password == passwords:
                        print "\n Access Granted"
                        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                        menu()
                    else:
                        pass
                    print "\n Access Denied"
                    print "\n Please try again"
                    login()
            else:
                pass
            print "\n Access Denied"
            print "\n Please try again"
            login()
    else:
        login()
```

Answer (score 0):

In python, every function has it's own *nametable*, wich basically means that any changes at any variable are lost after the function has finished. If you want to change a so called *global variable* (a variable in the global namespace, the one outside the function) and not the *local variable* (a variable in the namespace of e.g. a function), you first have to declare it as global:

```
def foo():
    global accounts
    accounts = "whatever"
```

**That's the main problem.** But your code still won't properly work:
The way you are doing it, the username and the password do not have to fit, the just have to be in your accounts-dict, at any place:

```
for usernames in accounts: #Iteration over all usernames
            if username.lower() == usernames.lower():
                for passwords in accounts.values(): #Iteration over all passwords
                    if password == passwords:
                        print "\n Access Granted"
                        print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                        menu()
```

You'd better solve it like this:

```
for account in accounts.items():
    if account[0] == username and account[1] == password:
        print "\n Access Granted!!!"
```

There is another problem too: (function: newaccount())

```
for username in accounts:
                if username.lower() == newusername.lower():
                    print "\n Username already exists"
                    print " Please try again"
                    newaccount() #[1]
                else:
                    pass
                accounts[newusername] = newpassword
```

What you want to do: restart the function. But here, you are restarting the function *inside* the function that is already running. After #[1] has succesfully finished, your program is just going to proceed at the line after #[1] and change the passwort of a user that already exists. (Wich it shouldn't, does it?)

To fix this, just put the right code in the else-part and break the for loop if another instance of the function is doin' the job:

```
for username in accounts:
                if username.lower() == newusername.lower():
                    print "\n Username already exists"
                    print " Please try again"
                    newaccount()
                    break #!!!
                else: #!!
                    accounts[newusername] = newpassword
                    print "\n Account Created"
                    print "\n--------------------------------------------"
                    startup()
```

...hopefully it's clear what I mean...